# Export Chrome for Android's history

Tags: chrome-for-android, export, browser-history

Is there a way to export the entire browser history from Chrome under Android, in any file format (CSV, XML, whatever)?

I have Chrome 42.0.2311.111 under Android 4.2.2.

Comment: Desktop-based Chrome allows for the installation of an addon that handles this. Its name is _Export History_. It does not seem to be available for Android; nor is there a comparable item. See the Chrome Web Store for further information.

Comment: @wbogacz Is there an extension or a program that you think can export the whole SQLite database into a CSV or XML file? I've written an answer below which can export the database but not into the said extensions.

Comment: @Firelord - check this query on stackoverflow: [http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sqlite+csv+export+is%3Aquestion](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sqlite+csv+export+is%3Aquestion)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) to download a JSON file of your Android Chrome history.

You can also download your bookmarks, along with a lot of other Google data.

Answer (score 3):

[Chrome doesn't allow backup using ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/117334/96277) and there are no extensions available for mobile version so you should have root access before you proceed further.

1. Grab the `History` file from the location `/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/` into PC. A [Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ROOT+EXPLORER) may help.
2. Install an SQLite manager such as [SQLiteman](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqliteman/files/sqliteman/) or [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) in PC.

   Both has the option under menu bar to export the database into an SQL file or a particular table into CSV file.

Well at least you now know where the history is stored, so you may find a relevant software to directly export the database into a CSV or XML file.

Answer (score 1):

If the tabs are still open you may find the following useful, via [dev.to - When you never close tabs on your mobile Chrome browser](https://dev.to/piczmar_0/when-you-never-close-tabs-on-your-mobile-chrome-browser-2boj). Not quite a solution here, but was what I was looking for when I came across this question.

## Export open tabs

Chrome's [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging) has a [remote-debugging-legacy](https://web.archive.org/web/20181005003253/https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging-legacy) mode that allows you to view tabs on a connected computer via `adb`.

#### Set up adb

1. First, install the [Android Command Line Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools) from Android Studio.
2. [Enable developer mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options#enable) on your phone by going to `Settings > About Phone > Build Number` and tapping 7 times
3. Enable USB debug mode from `Settings > Developer options` or `Settings > System > Advanced > Developer options`. This menu will only be visible after the previous step.
4. Connect to laptop and verify with `./adb devices -l`. You may need to [configure adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device#setting-up) and grant permission from your phone.

#### Connect to chrome remote devtools

Once your phone is set up with `adb` you can:

```
# Connect to Chrome Android's legacy debugging API
./adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote

# Visit http://localhost:9222 to verify, then
curl http://localhost:9222/json/list > mobile-tabs.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to export ALL your history from ALL devices under your Google Account on practically any browser. It's generally easiest to do it from your desktop, however.

Answer (score 0):

Touch the 3 dots on right top of screen.
choose "history"
when it loads, again touch 3 dots and choose "print"
Give new filename to save to
then scroll to bottom of history and choose "older".
after the page loads, repeat the above.

A hassle, but it works for me...
Later you can use various apps to combine the created .pdf files.
Oh, if this works for you, then..
"You're welcome".