# How can I find my Chrome bookmarks from Windows?

Tags: bookmarks

I dropped my Galaxy S4 SGH-M919 running KitKat not rooted and the screen broke. I can connect to PC using a USB. I was able to copy all the other data I needed using this method. But I had a few bookmarks in Chrome i would like to copy. I can't find these files anywhere I look. 
I don't have my android chrome synced to anything. And I can't set that up at this point. Is there any way this is information is findable?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, you can't access those bookmarks from the PC that easily.

#### Why so?

Because Android's UMS and MTP only gives you access to content under `/storage`. Chrome's bookmarks are stored in its data directory (`/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Bookmarks`). A normal user doesn't have the privileges required to  access `/data` directly.

Even ADB backup isn't allowed because [`android:allowBackup="false"`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#allowbackup) is set in Chrome's Manifest file.

[image]

---

While the device is not rooted, I should mention in brief methods to get those files when the device is rooted:

1. Use a root file explorer like [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) to access Chrome's data directory. Copy the bookmark file to SD card, and then use PC to copy it from SD card.

   You can use `adb pull` directly or indirectly as well.
2. [Run a file server like FTP](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/106323/96277) and set it's root directory at `/data/data/`. Access the server on PC using Wi-Fi/hotspot or USB tethering. This is the direct access I like to have.

There are other methods for rooted devices, but because the screen broke and the device is not rooted, the chances are none. Sorry!