# I wish to export Chrome history synced from a mobile device as a csv list, but this information is not stored in the 'History' file. Where is it?

Tags: sync, chrome-for-android, history

`...AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile #\History` usually has all URLs that you have visited, and you can open this up using DB Browser for SQLite. While I can hit Ctrl-H and see the links I've visited on my synced Android device, they are not there when I pull up the History file on the browser, so they must be stored elsewhere. I could not find any relevant Google results that answers my question, however.

What is the easiest way to export my Android Chrome history as a CSV file? And where is the synced history stored?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, do you want to do this using the PC only, or is it okay to also use the Android device? For Android directly: [Export Chrome for Android's history](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110053/44325)

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize this was an option. Although this doesn't directly answer my question, it nonetheless solves my issue. Thanks for the suggestion.